# Fabric / Firebase integration in Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-fabric

I am having difficulties with integrating `Firebase` and `Fabric` in my `Unity` project. I have eventually managed to get them to work together by installing the `Firebase` plugin then the `Fabric` plugin (it never worked the other way round). The issue is that I only see Firebase events in my Firebase console and no Fabric/Answers events (which I can see in Fabric so I know that there are events fired).

**Question1**: I am using `Unity` to generate my APK, could it be the issue and should I use Android Studio with gradle?

**Question2**: I have tried to build my app in Android Studio with gradle but I get an error when I start my app:

```
Didn't find class "io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.domain.appname-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.domain.appname-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

As I am new to gradle, what is a correct gradle for such a project (ie Unity with Firebase and Fabric)?

For information my `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
        applicationId 'com.domain.appname'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('xxxxx')
        storePassword 'xxxxxx'
        keyAlias 'xxxxxx'
        keyPassword 'xxxxxx'
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I went through the process one more time and now found an error in Fabric console under `Tools->Firebase` saying that my `Crashlytics SDK` is not up to date. 
[Crashlytics SDK is not up to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lTgR.png)

I have reinstalled the latest Fabric/Crashlytics Unity plugin from [Fabric for Unity plugin](https://www.fabric.io/downloads/unity). In Unity it shows up as `Crashlytics v1.2.5` which is the latest version indicated on Fabric: [Fabric changelog](https://docs.fabric.io/unity/changelog.html#august-3-2017)

This is when I am now wondering if by using gradle I would be able to somehow update my Fabric SDK.

Comment: You should be fine with having Unity generate your apk. Have you linked your app between Fabric and Firebase? https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/android-export-firebase.html

Comment: @Alexizamerican thanks for your help. My app is linked between Fabric and Firebase. I have added an update to my question as going through the process again, I can see now that the issue might be that Crashlytics SDK is not up to date which is strange as I have the latest unity plugin for Fabric that I could find.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. I've confirmed with the team that we haven't updated our Unity SDK to support the Fabric Answers to Firebase integration yet. I'm working with the team to ship an update so that we support this. Stay tuned for now and I'll add an update once it's live.

Comment: Thanks for the information. While waiting for an update, any advice on gradle would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Crashyalytics and Firebase Messaging both change your androidManifest.xml.  Unfortunately you have to merge the changes.

Hope this helps!

Firebase Messaging adds (at least)

`<!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
         UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
         notification data payloads in the background. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity"`

Fabric adds at least: 
`android:name="io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication"`

David